# In mllib LinearRegressionWithSGD, I can not control numIterations, why?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have one ml task, 34461 samples and I use LinearRegressionWithSGD to train model. But the results of the two training result(MSE and Correlation) are the same:

train model (setNumIterations(**5**))

```
val linearRegressionWithSGD: LinearRegressionWithSGD = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
linearRegressionWithSGD.setIntercept(true)
linearRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.setStepSize(0.1)
linearRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.setNumIterations(5)
```

train model (setNumIterations(**10000**))

```
val linearRegressionWithSGD: LinearRegressionWithSGD = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
linearRegressionWithSGD.setIntercept(true)
linearRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.setStepSize(0.1)
linearRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.setNumIterations(10000)
```

I can not control the number of iterations, but why?

Comment: Never used this lib, but according to the docs you can't set stepsize and iterations with this setter-approach. Only setting intercept is allowed. The others are set during Classifier-setup. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegressionWithSGD.html)

Comment: Thanks your answer. I can set stepsize use `linearRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.setStepSize(0.1)`, but i can't set numIterations. I still don't know why.